# Shebang line in Dart scripts (the portable way)?

Tags: dart, shebang

Let's say I have a Dart script called `dart-test`. I would like to distribute this script and make it so that users just have to put it in a folder in their `$PATH`, and execute it from anywhere just by typing `dart-test` in their terminal.

For the sake of this question, let's pretend I am the user `test` on my machine. I am on Mac OS X and installed the Dart binary with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). The `dart` binary lies in `/home/test/.brew/bin` and is in the $PATH.

Consequently, the following works:

```
$ cat <<HEREDOC > ~/.brew/bin/dart-test
#!/home/test/.brew/bin/dart
main() => print('Dart shebang works!');
HEREDOC

$ chmod u+x ~/.brew/bin/dart-test

$ dart-test
Dart shebang works!
```

The problem is that **the Dart shebang I use is not portable**, my script won't work on any other computer than mine. Is there a portable way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Considering Dart is kind of like Python and Ruby in the way it executes, I just looked at the standard way of doing it in those two languages. The `env` binary.)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env dart
```

Seems to be the way. It will look for `dart` binaries in the user's environment, and apparently enables simple Dart scripts to be executed from anywhere, provided the Dart VM is installed and in the `$PATH`.